# VTL with AWS S3 in Veeam

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, veeam, starwind

After implementing the solution based on the following manual - https://www.driftar.ch/2017/06/13/veeam-using-starwind-vtl-with-aws-s3-in-veeam/ and successfully configuring the solution, but the main difficulty that I have encountered is with the upload of the Tapes to the bucket, it just doesn't seem to work. Where could  I have gone wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Mind sharing your screenshots (edit them to hide specific acc names and local paths).

Answer (score 2):

After a quick guide review, I concern the issue can be caused because of wrongly inputted credentials or configured permissions in AWS.

Ensure:

1. you have chosen right AWS bracket
2. user permissions are configured to allow connection
3. in Replications Settings menu the right credentials are entered.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the attention, but i managed to resolve the issue on my own, seems like the issue was based on the misconfiguration of the bucket policies.

To set bucket policies, use these documents as a reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html

Comment: Did you use non-allowed characters in the path?